# Are there functions for converting Earth coordinate systems within the standard Anaconda installer?

Tags: python, anaconda, coordinates, coordinate-transformation

I specifically want to convert [LLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographic_coordinate_system) (latitude, longitude, altitude) data into [ECEF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECEF) (earth-centered, earth-fixed). (LLA data is [WGS84](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Geodetic_System#WGS84).)

Is there a function for this within the packages included with the installer for [anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com)?

It would be good if this package can do more than just LLA to ECEF, such as back-conversions and other coordinate frames (e.g. [ENU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_tangent_plane_coordinates)).

---

The rest of this is just clarification:

In other words, assume I have vanilla anaconda installed on a computer and can't install new packages. (Linux, 64-bit, for question completeness.)

I know the [pyproj](https://github.com/pyproj4/pyproj) package has a function, but according to a [list](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/packages/py3.7_linux-64/) on the anaconda website it is not included in the installer. There are a lot of packages included with the installer and I suspect the functionality exists in one of them but searching on Stack Overflow, Google, and anaconda docs so far isn't producing answers.

Edit: Furthermore, I am aware that a function to do the one-way transform between LLA and ECEF is only around a dozen lines of code and the math is publicly available. But, I would like to find that a package has the functionality for coordinate transformations. (Three main reasons: (1) It will be useful to have the reverse transformation, and transformations to other systems. (2) I like community-supported software and won't have to type and integrate my own package. (3) I'm curious.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[astropy's EarthLocation](https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/api/astropy.coordinates.EarthLocation.html)

```
from astropy.coordinates import EarthLocation
longitude = -76.899626  # degrees, West (so negative), AKA 283.10037 degrees East
latitude = 39.163002  # degrees
x = EarthLocation.from_geodetic(longitude, latitude)
x.geocentric

Out:
(<Quantity 1122390.43640202 m>,
 <Quantity -4823042.93548404 m>,
 <Quantity 4006364.03705792 m>)

x.geocentric[0].value  # the ECEF x-value

Out: 1122390.4364020245
```